# How to keep JQuery UI Dialog open after clicking on a server side asp.net button control?

Tags: jquery, dialog, postback

I have a JQuery Dialog, and a ASP.NET button, when the dialog is open, and I click on the ASP.NET button, it refresh the page and the Dialog gone. Unless I put the button into a UpdatePanel, but I hates UpdatePanel, Is there any other way to have keep the dialog open when user clicking on controls on the page which will fire a postback? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

during postback of aspnet btn, use this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript() to relaunch the same JQuery dialog that was launched earlier

Comment: I am not quite understand, but the text content in the dialog will be lost after re-launch and it might open the dialog everytime during postback?

Comment: No if you enabled viewstate for aspx page and jquery dialog controls are ASPNET controls.

Comment: I added: Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "dialogscript", "$('#dialog').dialog('open');", true);  into PageLoad, but it still disappear when I press a button.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you have a LinkButton in the popup you need to register the script every time like this...

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "KeepPopup", "<script type=text/javascript> PopItUp(); </script>");
}
```